# Utilizar PhantomJS en C#

Tags: c#, selenium

Como puedo utilizar PhantomJS en C#?

Agrege a mi proyecto Selenium, y PhantomJS, y se puede ver el ejecutable en mi proyecto.
Pero al tratar de usarlo, no puedo, unicamente con Firefox y Chrome, logro hacerlo andar, pero no encuentro la forma de poder usarlo como navegador, para hacer web scraping.

Basicamente para utilizar el driver de Firefox o Chrome, se incluye. `using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;`
En videos vi que al final ponian PhantomJS, pero no da resultados.

Debo utilizar una version anterior de Selenium?

Comment: Selenium y PhantomJS se utilizan para realizar test de integracion al automatizar las acciones del browser, pero lo deberias usar con NUnit, no entiendo lo de usarlo como navegador, quieres ver la pagina un form?

Comment: Al parecer me informe mal, estoy tratando de hacer web scraping, en una pagina de forex, y hay muchas partes con javascript de las cuales no puedo extraer la informacion que necesito, me dijeron que para hacerlo, utilizara Selenium y PhantomJS. 
Que me recomiendas hacer?

Comment: ¿ Has intentado usar Chrome Headless ?  Considerando que intentas hacer Web Scraping te dejo un articulo que escribi https://aspnetcoremaster.com/web/scraping/c%23/advientocsharp/dotnet/selenium/2018/12/24/web-scraping-con-csharp.html